# Implement Authentication in CXF WebServices using WSS4J (SOAP)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am trying to implement authentication using username/password in my webservices. Currently I learned CXF and how to configure stuff, but for the life of me, I just cant wrap my head around the security part.

I create the Java classes from WSDL using CXF. So this is my XML configuration for a webservice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<jaxws:endpoint id="pacService" implementor="com.logicalprovisioning.internal.PacWS" address="/PacRequestSoapHttpPort">
    <jaxws:properties>
        <entry key="exceptionMessageCauseEnabled" value="true" />
        <entry key="security.callback-handler" value="com.logicalprovisioning.webservices.clients.autheticate.AuthenticationCallback"/>
    </jaxws:properties>
</jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

The AuthenticationCallback entry I added as a part of the validation of the username password.

My AutheitcationCallback currently looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

import org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSPasswordCallback;

public class AuthenticationCallback {

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

        WSPasswordCallback wsPasswordCallback = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

        if (wsPasswordCallback.getIdentifier().equals("TIM")) {
            wsPasswordCallback.setPassword("my_password");
        }
    }
}
```

It is a rough draft for now.

I have a client written which I use to initialize the WebService (an abstract class), and inherit it for use in different webservices.

```
public abstract class WebServiceClientBase implements HandlerResolver, SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    protected int connectTimeout;

    protected String endPointUrl;
    protected String password;
    protected String userName;

    protected Logger logger = null;

    private Service service = null;


    public WebServiceClientBase () {
        super();
    }

    public void init() {

        // Set the security handler
        getService().setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolverImpl());

        // Setting endpoint URL and timeout...
        getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.receiveTimeout", connectTimeout);
        getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("javax.xml.ws.client.connectionTimeout", connectTimeout);
        getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);


        Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        headers.put("Content-Type", Collections.singletonList("application/soap+xml"));
        headers.put(Message.ENCODING, Collections.singletonList("UTF-8"));

        getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo arg0) {

        List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();

        handlerChain.add(this);

        return handlerChain;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext soapMessageContext) {

        if (!((Boolean) soapMessageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)). booleanValue()) {
            return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

    protected Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    protected void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    protected abstract BindingProvider getBindingProvider();
}
```

This is how far I have got. I am not sure how do I connect authentication information along with the webservice call.

Any pointers would be helpful. Also am I on the right track to begin with? I might have run into a dead end by going over all the tutorials and examples.

Comment: `I am not sure how do I connect authentication information along with the webservice call`  are you talking about basic auth or some WS-Security related authentication?

Comment: WS-Security is the one i am looking at. https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html . I read this guide, and looked up examples of it. But still couldn't sink my teeth into it.

Comment: As far as I understood your question, you are looking for a way to add the authentication information to your client request? You can either try to define the `ws-security` properties and the client callback handler [as outlined in this blog](http://glenmazza.net/blog/entry/cxf-usernametoken-profile) or use a `WSS4JOutInterceptor` which references your callback handler as shown [in this blog](https://dev.to/grodzickir/soap-security-using-wss4j-in-apache-cxf-in-java-kotlin-2hah)

Comment: Thanks for the blog link. I will give it a shot. I will come back i find something that i dont understand

Comment: @RomanVottner The two links were helpful. I got a little further than before. But I am stuck on the aspect of how to add Token/Password information on a client that is created by CXF wsdl2java. Most of the examples I find, out there, the webservices are written from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this assuming com.logicalprovisioning.internal.PacWS is your jaxws generated PortType class...

```
...
com.logicalprovisioning.internal.PacWS pacWsPort = getService().get...Port();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.getClient(pacWSPort);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, AuthenticationCallback.class.getName());
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "TIM");
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(props);
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

// you can then call @WebMethod annotated methods on your PacWS object, and it should populate the wss-security soap header
```

Some of the above code can probably be replaced by configuration in the cxf xml configuration file